# in vim how can you insert the current date/time into a note

Tags: vim, formatting, code-snippets

What script might i use in (vanilla) Vim to insert a snippet with the current date and time into each and every new note generated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use for example:

```
:pu=strftime('%c')
```

To put a timestamp into a file in the default timestamp format. The format is adjustable.

You could bind this action to a key (here F5 as an example). Put it to your .vimrc file without the colon in the beginning to make it permanent.

```
:nnoremap <F5> "=strftime("%c")<CR>P
```

More examples: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Insert_current_date_or_time

Comment: Appended to my notes intro-snippet, cheers!                                                                          nnoremap ,mm :.-1read $HOME/.vim/intro.md<CR>"=strftime("%c")<CR>pjA

Answer (score 4):

In my case I have an insert abbreviation, so, wenever I am typing I just do 'idate'

```
inoreabbrev idate <C-R>=strftime("%b %d %Y %H:%M")<CR>
```

Just change the "strftime" to fit your needs

Comment: Hi sergio, would you mind just elaborating on what "inoreabbrev" is/means, is this something specific to vim? Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: iabb means insert abreviation, inoreabb means that it can nob be reabreviated as part of other abbreviation "noreabbreviate". So, as you can see it is indeed a very specific vim jargon. For more see `:h inorea[bbrev]` where `[bbrev]` can be omited.